# FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm creating a .net core console application where some of the libraries are using SignalR.
I have installed "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" from nuget package manager and also added the same in Program.cs file as below.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateDefaultBuilder().Build();
            using IServiceScope serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope();
            IServiceProvider provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
            var workerInstance = provider.GetRequiredService<Worker>();
            workerInstance.DoWork();
            host.Run();
        }

        static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder()
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app =>
                {
                    app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                })
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {                    
                    services.AddSignalRCore();
                    services.AddSignalR();
                });
        }
}
```

I have added AddSignalRCore in the ConfigurationServices. Is there any anywhere else I need to add the reference or is there any other step missing? Because when I run the code, it gives an error:

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. The located assembly's manifest
> definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)

Comment: Don't install the nuget package unless you're running on netcoreapp 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screenshot of your csproj package management file? I did not find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, Version=3.1.0.0`. This version.

How you want to use SignalR in combination with asp.net core can download these packages:

Server NuGet Package：

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Client NuGet packages：

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/)